# From R to PostgreSQL. dbWritetable() accent letters problem

Tags: r, postgresql

From R to PostgreSQL, I upload a data frame with accents letter using RPostgreSQL package and when I query IN PostgreSQL, it doesn't show right characters.

- I've checked my data frame is UTF-8 coded. (function set_utf8 code below)
- I've checked the database from PostgreSQL is UTF-8 encoded. (see code below)
- I already know how to solve the problem when query (dbGetQuery()) from R
- I want to get right characters IN the PostgreSQL, because I will be querying from other coding languages. I use R only to generate data and upload it to the Psql data base.

```
# Connection

db_host <- "localhost"    
db_port <-  db_port_number           
db_name <- "db_Name"  
db_user <- "db_username"       
db_pass <- "password"  

drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")

con <- dbConnect(drv, 
                 dbname = db_name,
                 host = db_host, port = db_port,
                 user = db_user, password = db_pass)


# Check data base encoding

dbGetQuery(con, "SHOW server_encoding;")
# Result:   server_encoding
#           1            UTF8

# Data frame

df <- data.frame(Order = 1:3, Name = c("Cía de Cereales", "Compañía Paraná", "Ondulación"))

df <- set_utf8(df)

# Upload

 dbWriteTable(con, 
             "df",    
             fileEncoding = "UTF-8", 
             value = df,              
             append = TRUE, 
             row.names = FALSE)

dbDisconnect(con)
dbUnloadDriver(drv)

# #  Subfunction # #

set_utf8 <- function(x) {

# Declare UTF-8 encoding on all character columns:
    chr <- sapply(x, is.character)
    x[, chr] <- lapply(x[, chr, drop = FALSE], `Encoding<-`, "UTF-8")

 # Same on column names:
    Encoding(names(x)) <- "UTF-8"
    x
}
```

```
SELECT * FROM df;
```

Actual result:

```
 Order |      Name
-------+-----------------
     1 | CÝa de Cereales
     2 | Compa±Ýa Paranß
     3 | Ondulaci¾n
(3 filas)
```

Expected result:

```
 Order |      Name
-------+-----------------
     1 | Cía de Cereales
     2 | Compañía Paraná
     3 | Ondulación
(3 filas)
```